# How to set POST fileupload parameter in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `API` which receives POST file upload

like this

`curl -X POST -F upfile=@_mat/test.wav http://localhost:8008/upload/`

The file is send as `upfile`

my source code is like this below where can I set `upfile`??

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
 
const g_port = 8008;
const g_api = `http://localhost:${g_port}`;


class SpPage extends Component {
   state = {
      selectedFile: null
    };
    
    onFileChange = event => {
      // Update the state
      this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    };
    
    // On file upload (click the upload button)
    onFileUpload = () => {
      // Create an object of formData
      const formData = new FormData();
      // Update the formData object
      formData.append(
        "myFile",
        this.state.selectedFile,
        this.state.selectedFile.name
      );
      console.log(this.state.selectedFile);
      // Request made to the backend api
      // Send formData object
      axios.post(`${g_api}/upload/`, formData)
      .then(res =>{
         console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err=>{
         console.log(err);
      });
    };
    
    // File content to be displayed after
    // file upload is complete
    fileData = () => {
      if (this.state.selectedFile) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>File Details:</h2>
            <p>File Name: {this.state.selectedFile.name}</p>
            <p>File Type: {this.state.selectedFile.type}</p>
             
            <p>
              Last Modified:{" "}
              {this.state.selectedFile.lastModifiedDate.toDateString()}
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            <br />
            <h4>Choose before Pressing the Upload button</h4>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };
    
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>
              GeeksforGeeks
            </h1>
            <h3>
              File Upload using React!
            </h3>
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                <button onClick={this.onFileUpload}>
                  Upload!
                </button>
            </div>
          {this.fileData()}
        </div>
      );
    }
  
}
export default SpPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `formData` and send it to the `/upload` endpoint in the body of the request. so you can append your `upfile` in the current `formData`:

```
// rest of the codes ...

  formData.append(
    "myFile",
    this.state.selectedFile,
    this.state.selectedFile.name
  );
   
  formData.append(
    "upfile",
    myWaveFile
  )
```